# External hash (#) link to go & open specific tabs not working with Bootstrap 5 (Ok on 4)?

Tags: tabs, bootstrap-5

My goal is to use an external Hash (#) url link  to go & open specifics Bootstrap tabs. I like the same functionality as an html anchors link permitting a link in any pages, emails whatever to go to the right webpage, scroll to view &, in this case, open the related tab.

**This is a working Bootstrap 4 example on CodePen**
—> https://codepen.io/Chacapamac/pen/RwQZvBX

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-spacer"> <a href="#forgot-password" class="tab-link">Go to Forget Password</a> 
<br /><br />
Other test link here
</div>
<div class="big-spacer"> <a href="#forgot-password" class="tab-link">Go to Forget Password</a> </div>
—————————————————————————————————————————————
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="log-in-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#log-in" role="tab" aria-controls="log-in" aria-selected="true">Log in</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="forgot-password-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#forgot-password" role="tab" aria-controls="forgot-password" aria-selected="false">Forgot password</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="sign-up-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#sign-up" role="tab" aria-controls="sign-up" aria-selected="false">Sign up</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="log-in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="log-in-tab">
        Login tab<br />
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="forgot-password" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="forgot-password-tab">
        Forgt password tab
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sign-up" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sign-up-tab">
        Sign-up tab
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
I also try to replace href in the nav by data-bs-target
```

**CSS**

```
html { 
  padding: 20px !Important;
  margin: 20px !Important;
}

div.big-spacer { height: 800px;

}
```

**Script**

```
$('.tab-link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $('[data-toggle="tab"][href="' + this.hash + '"]');
    
    target.trigger('click');
    target[0].scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::: **PROBLEM BOOTSTRAP 5** ::::::::::

My Bootstrap 5 example is scrolling to view but **not opening the tab**.
The tabs are working fine.
—> https://codepen.io/Chacapamac/pen/wvyPLdG

**My code:**
Only changes from the Bootstap 4 code** - I replace “data-toggle” by “data-bs-toggle” (in html, js)

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-spacer"> <a href="#forgot-password" class="tab-link">Go to Forget Password</a> 
<br /><br />
Other test link here
</div>
<div class="big-spacer"> <a href="#forgot-password" class="tab-link">Go to Forget Password</a> </div>
—————————————————————————————————————————————
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="log-in-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#log-in" role="tab" aria-controls="log-in" aria-selected="true">Log in</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="forgot-password-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#forgot-password" role="tab" aria-controls="forgot-password" aria-selected="false">Forgot password</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="sign-up-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#sign-up" role="tab" aria-controls="sign-up" aria-selected="false">Sign up</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="log-in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="log-in-tab">
        Login tab<br />
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="forgot-password" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="forgot-password-tab">
        Forgot password tab
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sign-up" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sign-up-tab">
        Sign-up tab
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
I also try to replace href in the nav by data-bs-target
```

**CSS**

```
html { 
  padding: 20px !Important;
  margin: 20px !Important;
}

div.big-spacer { height: 800px;

}
```

**Script**

```
$('.tab-link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $('[data-bs-toggle="tab"][href="' + this.hash + '"]');
    
    target.trigger('click');
    target[0].scrollIntoView(true);
});
```